# Sharing data between slice reducers when using createReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a ReactJS app in `TypeScript` with `redux` and I'm using `redux-toolkit` to build my reducers. As the app has grown larger, I want to start refactoring my reducers.

My redux state looks like the following:

```
{
  customers: Customers[],
  orders: {
    state1: SomeIndependentState1,
    state2: SomeIndependentState2,
    state3: SomeDependentState2,
    state4: SomeDependentState3,
  }
}
```

The `customers` and `orders` slices are independent and I can easily write two separate reducers for them, combining them with `combineReducers` later.

Now, I want to break down my `orders` reducer further.

- `state1` and `state2` are completely independent.
- `state3` depends on data from `state1`.
- `state4` depends on data from `state1` and `state2`.

Is there a way to continue using `createReducer` from `redux-toolkit` (or some other functionality from the toolkit) to create reducers for each *nested slice* within the `orders` slice?

As I've started rewriting my reducer for `orders`, here's what I have so far:

```
export const ordersReducer = (state: Orders, action: AnyAction) => {
  return {
    state1: state1Reducer(state?.state1, action),
    state2: state2Reducer(state?.state2, action),
    state3: {}, // not sure how to write a reducer for this slice and satisfy its dependency on state1
    state4: {}, // not sure how to write a reducer for this slice and staisfy its dependency on state1 and state2
  }
};

const initialState1: State1 = {};
export const state1Reducer = createReducer(initialState1, (builder) => 
  builder
    .addCase(...)
    .addCase(...)
);

const initialState2: State2 = {};
export const state2Reducer = createReducer(initialState2, (builder) => 
  builder
    .addCase(...)
    .addCase(...)
);
```

Note: I don't have control over the structure of my redux state. I'm not completely tied to using `redux-toolkit` but would need a good justification to have my team move away from it.

Comment: What you mean by dependecy on state1 and state2. Can you give an example

Comment: In order to compute state3, I need information from the action payload and from the data stored in state2.

Comment: state3 = state3Reducer(state?.state3, action, state2)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass everything to the reducer that it needs. In this case, I would pass the whole `orders` state instead of passing `state1`, `state2`, `state3`, etc.

```
export const ordersReducer = (orders: Orders, action: AnyAction) => {
  return {
    // ...
    state3: state3Reducer(orders, action),
    // ...
  }
};

const initialState3: State3 = {};
export const state3Reducer = createReducer(initialState3, (builder) => 
  builder
    .addCase(someAction, (orders, action) => orders.state3 + orders.state1) // or anything else
    .addCase(...)
);
```

I renamed `state` to `orders`. I know that the canonical docs use `state` a lot, but that will get very confusing very quickly.

This is of course if `state3` depends on the old `state1`. If it depends on the new value then you must have all the data that `state3` needs in your action and the old `state1`. (Which leads back to the above solution). If you do not, your reducers are not pure functions.

Don't stress too much about your reducers. They have to be pure functions but they can have any number and type of args and return anything. They don't always have to strictly match the "relevant state prop to the relevant state prop".

Comment: This doesn't quite work, unfortunately. createReducer, which is a utility function from redux-toolkit, does not accept the full state. So I cannot pass orders to it directly. I ended up creating a wrapper function that accepts the full state and internally calls createReducer with the appropriate slice. I'm using variable scoping to get access to the full state.